# Scrapy blocked during the scraping process

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy, blocking

I have a long (800 000 items needed) scraping process who block before finish.
First, I would like to apologize for this long question, with a lot of code... I preferred to give you as much information as possible.
I tried many things, read many other things but I can't solve the problem shown by this log:

```
[... everything works well ...]
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&email=...&tool=...&query_key=1&webenv=NCID_1_167674051_130.14.18.34_9001_1501674632_1806773429_0MetA0_S_MegaStore_F_1&retmode=xml&retstart=664200&retmax=100>
{'abstract': None,
 'authors': [{'affiliation_info': None, 'first_name': u'I', 'last_name': u'Kimura'},
             {'affiliation_info': None, 'first_name': u'T', 'last_name': u'Sugiyama'},
             {'affiliation_info': None, 'first_name': u'Y', 'last_name': u'Ito'}],
 'doi': None,
 'journal': u'Proceedings of the Society for Experimental Biology and Medicine. Society for Experimental Biology and Medicine (New York, N.Y.)',
 'keywords': [],
 'publication_year': u'1967',
 'scrape_session_id': 1,
 'title': u'Papillomatous growth in sole from Wakasa Bay area.',
 'url': u'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6027520'}
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scraper.pipelines] DEBUG: Prepare item.
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scraper.pipelines] DEBUG: Check if article already exist.
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scraper.pipelines] DEBUG: Begin authors processing.
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scraper.pipelines] DEBUG: Get or create author.
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scraper.pipelines] DEBUG: Get or create author.
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scraper.pipelines] DEBUG: Begin keywords processing.
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scraper.pipelines] DEBUG: Get or create journal.
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scraper.pipelines] DEBUG: Commit article.
2017-08-02 12:35:55 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&email=...&tool=...&query_key=1&webenv=NCID_1_167674051_130.14.18.34_9001_1501674632_1806773429_0MetA0_S_MegaStore_F_1&retmode=xml&retstart=664200&retmax=100>
{'abstract': None,
 'authors': [{'affiliation_info': None, 'first_name': u'V H', 'last_name': u'Donaldson'},
             {'affiliation_info': None, 'first_name': u'O D', 'last_name': u'Ratnoff'}],
 'doi': None,
 'journal': u'Proceedings of the Society for Experimental Biology and Medicine. Society for Experimental Biology and Medicine (New York, N.Y.)',
 'keywords': [],
 'publication_year': u'1967',
 'scrape_session_id': 1,
 'title': u'Effect of some analogues of bradykinin upon vascular permeability.',
 'url': u'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6027514'}
2017-08-02 12:36:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 506 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 48229 items (at 501 items/min)
2017-08-02 12:37:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 506 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 48229 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-02 12:38:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 506 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 48229 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-02 12:39:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 506 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 48229 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-02 12:40:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 506 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 48229 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-02 12:41:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 506 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 48229 items (at 0 items/min)
[... infinite ...]
```

After `2017-08-02 12:36:32` the python processes are already running but nothing happen:

MySQL no longer receives requests:
[image: MySQL no longer receives requests]

Here is some informations of the TelnetConsole (after the blocking):

```
>>> est()
Execution engine status

time()-engine.start_time                        : 8502.19854903
engine.has_capacity()                           : False
len(engine.downloader.active)                   : 16
engine.scraper.is_idle()                        : False
engine.spider.name                              : pubmed_spider
engine.spider_is_idle(engine.spider)            : False
engine.slot.closing                             : False
len(engine.slot.inprogress)                     : 16
len(engine.slot.scheduler.dqs or [])            : 0
len(engine.slot.scheduler.mqs)                  : 6605
len(engine.scraper.slot.queue)                  : 0
len(engine.scraper.slot.active)                 : 0
engine.scraper.slot.active_size                 : 0
engine.scraper.slot.itemproc_size               : 0
engine.scraper.slot.needs_backout()             : False

>>> stats.get_stats()
{
    'spider_name': 'Pubmed',
    'memusage/startup': 63430656,
    'scrape_session_id': 1,
    'log_count/INFO': 148,
    'downloader/response_count': 506,
    'downloader/response_bytes': 20485075,
    'item_dropped_count': 2182,
    'item_dropped_reasons_count/DropItem': 2182,
    'scrape_session_query': 'skin',
    'log_count/DEBUG': 582414,
    'scheduler/dequeued': 522,
    'log_count/WARNING': 2183,
    'request_depth_max': 1,
    'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 2, 11, 50, 32, 57921),
    'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 522,
    'log_count/CRITICAL': 2,
    'memusage/max': 177164288,
    'downloader/request_bytes': 371843,
    'downloader/response_status_count/200': 506,
    'response_received_count': 506,
    'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 7127,
    'item_scraped_count': 48229,
    'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 522,
    'scheduler/enqueued': 7127,
    'downloader/request_count': 522
}
```

Here is my code:

**Spider**

```py
class PubmedSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pubmed_spider'

    pubmed_email = '...'
    pubmed_tool = '...'

    allowed_domains = ['eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov']

    base_url = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils'
    base_params = 'db=pubmed&email=%s&tool=%s' % (pubmed_email, pubmed_tool)

    root_itertag = 'PubmedArticle'
    namespaces = ()

    webenv = None

    scrape_session_id = None
    source_total_count = 0

    ret_max = 100

    def __init__(self, query=None, source=None, system_session=None, publi_sci_session=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PubmedSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.query = query
        self.source = source
        self.system_session = system_session
        self.publi_sci_session = publi_sci_session

    def get_esearch_url(self):
        return '%s/esearch.fcgi?%s&term=%s&retmax=1&usehistory=y%s' % \
               (self.base_url,
                self.base_params,
                self.query.query,
                '&webenv=%s' % self.webenv if self.webenv else '')

    def get_efetch_url(self, query_key, retstart, retmax):
        return '%s/efetch.fcgi?%s&query_key=%s&webenv=%s&retmode=xml&retstart=%s&retmax=%s' %\
                           (self.base_url,
                            self.base_params,
                            query_key,
                            self.webenv,
                            retstart,
                            retmax)

    def get_last_crawl_session(self, query):
        return self.system_session\
            .query(func.sum(ScrapeSession.items_scraped + ScrapeSession.items_dropped).label("total_items_scraped"))\
            .join(ScrapeSession.queries)\
            .filter(ScrapeSession.source == self.source)\
            .filter(Query.id == query.id)\
            .first()

    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(self.get_esearch_url(), callback=self.find_retmax)]

    def find_retmax(self, response):
        self.webenv = response.selector.xpath('/eSearchResult/WebEnv/text()').extract()[0]
        count = int(response.selector.xpath('/eSearchResult/Count/text()').extract()[0])
        query_key = response.selector.xpath('/eSearchResult/QueryKey/text()').extract()[0]
        last_session = self.get_last_crawl_session(self.query)
        self.source_total_count = count
        if not last_session.total_items_scraped:
            retmax = self.ret_max
        else:
            retmax = count - last_session.total_items_scraped
        if retmax is not None and retmax < 1:
            raise CloseSpider("No new publications for '%s'." % self.query.query)
        retstart = last_session.total_items_scraped
        offsets = [retstart]
        while retstart < count - self.ret_max:
            retstart += self.ret_max
            offsets.append(retstart)
        for offset in offsets:
            efetch_url = self.get_efetch_url(query_key, offset, self.ret_max)
            yield Request(efetch_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_article(self, response, node):
        authors_nodes = node.xpath('MedlineCitation/Article/AuthorList/Author')
        authors = self.parse_tag(response, authors_nodes, self.parse_author)
        loader = ItemLoader(item=PubmedArticleItem(), selector=node)
        loader.add_xpath('title', 'MedlineCitation/Article/ArticleTitle/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('title', 'MedlineCitation/Article/VernacularTitle/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('abstract', 'MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/AbstractText/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('publication_year', 'MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate/Year/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('publication_year', 'MedlineCitation/DateCreated/Year/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('publication_year', 'MedlineCitation/DateRevised/Year/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('doi', 'PubmedData/ArticleIdList/ArticleId[@IdType="doi"]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('doi', 'MedlineCitation/Article/ELocationID[@EIdType="doi"]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('journal', 'MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/Title/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('keywords', 'MedlineCitation/KeywordList/Keyword/text()')
        loader.add_value('url', 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/')
        loader.add_xpath('url', 'MedlineCitation/PMID/text()')
        loader.add_value('authors', authors)
        loader.add_value('scrape_session_id', self.scrape_session_id)
        yield loader.load_item()

    def parse_author(self, response, node):
        loader = ItemLoader(item=PubmedAuthorItem(), selector=node)
        loader.add_xpath('last_name', 'LastName/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('first_name', 'ForeName/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('affiliation_info', 'AffiliationInfo/Affiliation/text()')
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_tag(self, response, nodes, callback):
        results = []
        for selector in nodes:
            results.append(callback(response, selector))
        return results

    def parse_nodes(self, response, nodes, callback):
        for selector in nodes:
            for result_item in iterate_spider_output(callback(response, selector)):
                yield result_item

    def parse(self, response, itertag=root_itertag):
        nodes = self._iternodes(response, itertag)
        return self.parse_nodes(response, nodes, self.parse_article)

    def _iternodes(self, response, itertag):
        for node in xmliter(response, itertag):
            self._register_namespaces(node)
            yield node

    def _register_namespaces(self, selector):
        for (prefix, uri) in self.namespaces:
            selector.register_namespace(prefix, uri)
```

**Pipeline**

```py
class ScraperPipeline(object):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = spider.publi_sci_session

        self.logger.debug('Prepare item.')
        item.prepare()

        def parse_affiliation(affiliation_string):
            email = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+.\w{2,}', affiliation_string)
            email = email[0] if len(email) > 0 else None
            return {'dirty': affiliation_string, 'email': email}

        self.logger.debug('Check if article already exist.')
        Article.check_exist(session, item['title'], item['doi'])

        # Authors
        authors = []
        self.logger.debug('Begin authors processing.')
        if 'authors' in item and item['authors'] is not None:
            for author_item in item['authors']:
                try:
                    author_item.prepare()
                except RuntimeWarning:
                    continue

                self.logger.debug('Get or create author.')
                author = get_or_create(session, Author, None,
                                       first_name=author_item['first_name'],
                                       last_name=author_item['last_name'])[0]

                if author in authors:
                    continue

                if 'affiliation_info' in author_item and author_item['affiliation_info'] is not None:
                    self.logger.debug('Parse author affilication.')
                    affiliation_info = parse_affiliation(author_item['affiliation_info'])

                    self.logger.debug('Get or create affilication.')
                    affiliation = get_or_create(session, Affiliation,
                                                defaults={'email': affiliation_info['email']},
                                                dirty=affiliation_info['dirty'])[0]

                    session.add(affiliation)
                    author.add_affiliation(session, affiliation, item['publication_year'])
                authors.append(author)

        # Keywords
        keywords = []
        self.logger.debug('Begin keywords processing.')
        for keyword_item in item['keywords']:
            self.logger.debug('Get or create keyword.')
            keyword = get_or_create(session, Keyword, None, keyword=keyword_item)[0]
            if keyword in keywords:
                continue
            keywords.append(keyword)

        # Journal
        self.logger.debug('Get or create journal.')
        journal = get_or_create(session, Journal, None, name=item['journal'])[0]

        # Article
        article = Article(
            title=item['title'],
            abstract=item['abstract'],
            publication_year=item['publication_year'],
            doi=item['doi'],
            journal=journal,
            keywords=keywords,
            authors=authors,
            scrape_session_id=spider.scrape_session_id
        )
        session.add(article)
        session.add(ArticleUrl(article=article, url=item['url']))
        self.logger.debug('Commit article.')
        session.commit()
        return item
```

If any of you had an idea, it would be really great. :)

Thank you in advance !